# MaxLength on WPF app does not work for Korean Language

Tags: c#, wpf, internationalization, textbox, maxlength

I'm having trouble trying to get the MaxLength property of a TextBox in WPF to work when I'm using a on screen keyboard with Korean language.

It just doesn't limit and also it won't give me any event other than TextChanged, so I didn't find a way to avoid the character being written on the screen.

Also, if i try to just remove the character just after being inserted and change the caret position to the end, the app just crashes without any exception during debugging.

I would really appreciate if you have any ideas on how could I fix it!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st,

```
textbox.PreviewTextInput += textbox_PreviewTextInput;

void textbox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox box = (TextBox) sender;
   e.Handled = box.Text.Length > 5;
}
```

2nd, post a bug to MS Connect

3rd, enable all exceptions Debug-Exceptions, then maybe not JustMyCode in options to see what happens.